# Can create HashMap with Spring but can't create Map

Tags: spring

I can do this in my applicationContext with Spring (3.0.5):

```
<bean id="map" class="java.util.HashMap" scope="prototype" >
    <constructor-arg>
        <map key-type="java.lang.String" value-type="java.lang.String">
            <entry key="Key 1" value="1" />
            <entry key="Key 2" value="2" />
        </map>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

And in my controller, I can autowired my map like this:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("map")
private HashMap<String, String> map;
```

It works fine, but if I do this:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("map")
private Map<String, String> map;
```

I get that:

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   matching bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency [map
>   with value type java.lang.String]: expected at least 1 bean which
>   qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency
>   annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true),
>   @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=map)}

My question is: Why I can't autowired my map with the interface when I can with the implementation ?

Thanks.

Comment: don't have a bean id of map, thats confusing

Comment: the real problem is: a map shouldn't be a spring bean at all in the first place. services should be beans, data shouldn't. If you really want a map bean, create a bean that holds a map and inject that.

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd why not you can inject anything and get benefits. There are no negative effects are there ? (assuming you give it a descriptive name)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

While declaring a bean of type collection, one cannot inject it via @Autowired. See below documentation from Spring:

[4.11.3 Fine-tuning annotation-based autowiring with qualifiers](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s11.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers)

> As a specific consequence of this semantic difference, beans which are
>   themselves defined as a collection or map type cannot be injected via
>   @Autowired since type matching is not properly applicable to them. Use
>   @Resource for such beans, referring to the specific collection/map
>   bean by unique name.

Thus instead of `@Autowired`, use `@Resource`:

```
@Resource
@Qualifier("map")
private Map<String, String> map;
```

Comment: But I can't use @Resource on constructor parameters. I need this to be via constructor

Answer (score 11):

Try to use `@Resource` instead of `@Autowired`

```
@Resource(name="map") 
private HashMap<String, String> map;
```

Check out the tip in [3.9.3 Fine-tuning annotation-based autowiring with qualifiers](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers) of Spring's documentation